# Plotly map hovers don't render in R

Tags: r, plotly

Using the [example code](https://plot.ly/r/bubble-maps/) from Plotly, the map hovers don't render in RStudio (or a compiled .html file using RMarkdown):

```
library(plotly) # version ‘4.7.1’
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_us_cities.csv')

df$q <- with(df, cut(pop, quantile(pop)))
levels(df$q) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"), "Quantile")
df$q <- as.ordered(df$q)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  subunitwidth = 1,
  countrywidth = 1,
  subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("white")
)

p <- plot_geo(df, locationmode = 'USA-states', sizes = c(1, 250)) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~lon, y = ~lat, size = ~pop, color = ~q, hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~paste(df$name, "<br />", df$pop/1e6, " million")
  ) %>%
  layout(title = '2014 US city populations<br>(Click legend to toggle)', geo = g)

p
```

I've also tried `hovertext` instead of `text` without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is due to a newer version of plot_ly that you are using (hoverinfo = "text" is no longer needed) : 
Try this:

```
library(plotly) # version ‘4.7.1’
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_us_cities.csv')

df$q <- with(df, cut(pop, quantile(pop)))
levels(df$q) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"), "Quantile")
df$q <- as.ordered(df$q)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  subunitwidth = 1,
  countrywidth = 1,
  subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("white")
)

p <- plot_geo(df, locationmode = 'USA-states', sizes = c(1, 250)) %>%  
  layout(title = '2014 US city populations<br>(Click legend to toggle)', geo = g) %>%  
  add_markers(x = ~lon, y = ~lat, size = ~pop, color = ~q, text = ~paste(df$name, "<br />", df$pop/1e6, " million")
              )  

p
```

It works on my RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

This was recently fixed in the dev version `devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly')`